# Subspaces of a quadratic space

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, quadratic-forms

I am reading about scissors congruence groups and subspaces of quadratic spaces have come up, but I'm not very familiar with these definitions and apologize in advance if something I wrote doesn't make sense. I would appreciate any intuition or references for my following questions.

First the setting I am working in:

Def: a geometry $X = (E, q)$ over the field k is a vector space $E$ equipped with a non-degenerate quadratic form $q$, and corresponding isometry group $I(X)$.

Def: A subspace $U$ of the quadratic form is a linear subspace of $E$ such that $q$ is non-degenerate.

My questions are:

1. In the case of the geometry defined by a quadratic form with signature $(n_-, n_+)$, I am wondering if specifying signature and dimension completely classifies the subspaces up to isometry?
2. I've seen someone refer to an isometric copy of a subspace, it was in the case of a hyperbolic or spherical geometry (so the equator inside $S^2$). However, if we have just a general quadratic form, what would this mean?
3. I am curious if there are conditions on the field? (though for the above questions, I would have happy to work in $\mathbb{R}$.